# add active class to menu item clicked add remove from others

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I want to add isActive class to an item menu when user click on this item, and remove isActive class from all others items.
I am trying to compare the id, this is the angularJS code:

```
$rootScope.isActive = function(idVal, event){ 
        return idVal === event.target.id;
    }
```

This is a part from Menu Html code:

```
 <ul class="sidebar-nav"> 
        <li>
            <a ui-sref="" id='101' ng-class="{active: isActive($event, 101)}">
                <span class='glyphicon  glyphicon-ban-circle glyph-sidebar'></span> 
                Rules
            </a>
            <ul class='dropdown sidebar-nav-dropdown' >
                <li>
                    <a href="">Transaction Mapping</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">File Setup</a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="">Code Setup</a>
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id='102' ng-class="{active: isActive($event, 102)}">
                <span class='glyphicon  glyphicon-ban-circle glyph-sidebar'></span>
                Administrative Rules
            </a>
            <ul class='dropdown sidebar-nav-dropdown'>
                <li>
                    <a ui-sref="admin.mapping-rules">Transaction Mapping</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ui-sref="admin.mapping-rules">File Setup</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ui-sref="admin.mapping-rules">Code Setup</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't use the root scope. You should use the scope of the controller associated to that view.

Second, your code doesn't make much sense. $event can be used as a parameter of a function called... to react to an event:

```
ng-click="doSomething($event)"
```

But with ng-class, there is no $event.

All you need to have in your scope is the ID (or name, or whatever identifies a menu item) of the selected menu item:

```
$scope.selectedMenuItem = null;
```

When an item is clicked, you need to change the selected menu item:

```
ng-click="selectMenuItem(101)"

$scope.selectMenuItem(item) {
    $scope.selectedMenuItem = item;
}
```

Then to associated a css class with the selected menu item, you simply need

```
ng-class="{active: selectedMenuItem === 101}"
```

That said, if all your links navigate to a given router state, you don't even need that selectedMenuItem. All you need is to add the active class if the current router state is the one the that the link allows navigating to (assuming $state is on your scope):

```
ng-class="{active: $state.includes('admin.mapping-rules')}
```